# Does distcp inherently use SSL/TLS to transfer file to AWS S3

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using distcp command to transfer files from a local Hadoop cluster to Amazon S3. This is the command I am using:

`hadoop distcp -D mapred.job.queue.name="somename" -Dfs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId="xxxx" -Dfs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey="xxxx" -m "100" -update -pugp  "hdfs:///path-in-hdfs" "s3n://path-to-s3"`

Will this command use SSL to transfer data?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that s3n is using the [jets3t](http://www.jets3t.org/toolkit/configuration.html) library under the hood. That documentation says:

> **s3service.https-only**
>   If true, all communication with S3 will be via encrypted HTTPS connections, otherwise communications will be sent unencrypted via HTTP
>   Default: true

So it does sound like https is on by default.